# Creating continues nested for loop

Tags: python, loops

Is it possible to write a function that adds more `for` loops to a nested loop. So lets say I have a function `for_loops(3)`.

```
    def for_loops(n):
        a = []
        for add_v in range(n):
            a.append("AB")

        for i in range(len(a[0])):
            for j in range(len(a[1])):
                for k in range(len(a[2])):
                    print(a[0][i]+" "+a[1][j]+" "+a[2][k])
   for_loops(3)
```

then `for_loops(4)`

```
    def for_loops(n):
        a = []
        for add_v in range(n):
            a.append("AB")

        for i in range(len(a[0])):
            for j in range(len(a[1])):
                for k in range(len(a[2])):
                    for l in range(len(a[3])):
                        print(a[0][i]+" "+a[1][j]+" "+a[2][k]+" "+a[3][l])
   for_loops(4)
```

Comment: You might want to look into doing something else. Either recursion, or just not having such crazily nested lists. There's not really a good way to do this in exactly this way.

Comment: Probably you could use `itertools.product` https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product
But I agree with Morgan Thrapp, this approach seems like it probably isn't ideal.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve a similar result using `itertools.product` which generates a Cartesian product

```
def for_loops(n):
    from itertools import product
    for row in product("AB", repeat = n):
        print " ".join(row)
```

The way it works is, given a set, it will generate the Cartesian product of n cardinality i.e.

```
(A, B) X (A, B) X (A, B) .... n
```

- For `n = 4`, this would be `(A, B) X (A, B) X (A, B) X (A, B)`
- For `n = 3`, this would be `(A, B) X (A, B) X (A, B)`

And example run with `n = 4` is shown below, which matches with the result you have from the 4 nested loop

```
>>> for_loops(4)
A A A A
A A A B
A A B A
A A B B
A B A A
A B A B
A B B A
A B B B
B A A A
B A A B
B A B A
B A B B
B B A A
B B A B
B B B A
B B B B
```

**Edit 1**

*Thanx, this does exactly what I want it to do but I'm trying to do it without using any built in function. –*

If you do not want to use any builtin function, the following might be an alternate approach for you

```
def for_loops(n):
    for i in range(2**n):
        print " ".join("AB"[int(j)] for j in "{:04b}".format(i))
```

Comment: Thanx, this does exactly what I want it to do but I'm trying to do it without using any built in function.